# Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've read a lot on other forums, they said that the error was that there was White-space before the session_start but I'm extremely sure there isn't, my file is encoded in UTF8 without BOM so that white-space problem should be fine and it's working perfectly on local (I'm using easyphp). Still, as soon as I put it online, it pops me those problem.anyone can help? They're telling those two lines of error online :

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent

This is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Comment: I can't believe `<?php session_start(); ?>` gives you that error, please post your full code.

Comment: Is that all the output you got? No file name and line number? No other output? Also, is that all the code you got, or is this included from another file?

Comment: Add `<?php ob_start() ?>` top of the page

Comment: <?php
session_start();
  $uname=$_SESSION['name'];
?><?php
session_start();
 $servername = "68.178.143.40";
$username = "applicant123";
$password = "Applicant@123";
$dbname = "applicant123";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$uname=$_SESSION['name'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM consultant WHERE username='uname' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   
   
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

Comment: This is my code if i am using session_start(); its shown above warning message.how to resolve this?

Comment: The username get from previous page using session

Comment: my webpage shows 
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/44/8512544/html/sarah_philip.php:10) in /home/content/44/8512544/html/sarah_philip.php on line 149 like this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Answer (score 0):

The warning means that the HTTP headers were already sent and they cannot be modified anymore. You have to make sure you do not send any content before `session_start`. Put it on top of your very first PHP script, before any `echo` or HTML and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly an error in your code - you have an else condition attached to a while loop and perhaps you posted it in error but why are there two session_start() calls? Assuming that this is one page!

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    $uname=$_SESSION['name'];
?>
<?php 
    /*session_start();*/
    $servername = "68.178.143.40"; 
    $username = "applicant123"; 
    $password = "Applicant@123"; 
    $dbname = "applicant123"; 

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
    if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } 
    $uname=$_SESSION['name']; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM consultant WHERE username='uname' "; 
    $result = $conn->query( $sql ); 
    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

    /* Here is a problem - there should be no "else" */
    /*
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {

    } else { 
        echo "0 results"; 
    }
    */


    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        /* do stuff with recordset */
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```